# Ruby on rails parse JSON file with rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have an url for JSON object which look like thaht :

```
{
 "sitesSessions" : {
   "910360_2" : {
    "name": "name",
    "adresse": "adresse"
   },
   "76590_1" : {
    "name": "name",
    "adresse": "adresse"
   }
 }
}
```

(this is just an example, the real JSON object is very long) and I want to access to "name" and "adresse" in this object.

I need to create a rake task that parse all the document and take name and adresse and insert these in an excel file.

But I don't know how to access to "name" and "adresse" because I have this "910360_2" or "76590_1" that are different for each object in the json ...

Does someone could help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy, I suggest you read [Ruby Hashes](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_hashes.html).

```
{
 "sitesSessions" : {
   "910360_2" : {
    "name": "name",
    "adresse": "adresse"
   },
   "76590_1" : {
    "name": "name",
    "adresse": "adresse"
   }
 }
}
>> require 'json'
=> true
>> JSON.parse(f)
=> {"sitesSessions"=>{"910360_2"=>{"name"=>"name", "adresse"=>"adresse"}, "76590_1"=>{"name"=>"name", "adresse"=>"adresse"}}}
>> JSON.parse(f)["sitesSessions"].values
=> [{"name"=>"name", "adresse"=>"adresse"}, {"name"=>"name", "adresse"=>"adresse"}]
>> JSON.parse(f)["sitesSessions"].values.map do |x|
>>   [x['name'], x['adresse']]
>> end
=> [["name", "adresse"], ["name", "adresse"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could just iterate return all values in the hash:

```
hash = JSON.parse(json)
hash['sitesSessions'].values
#=> [
#     {
#       "name": "name",
#       "adresse": "adresse"
#     },
#     {
#       "name": "name",
#       "adresse": "adresse"
#     }
#   ]
```